# Why do some web servers still provide information on vendor and version in the HTTP response headers

Tags: webserver, fingerprinting

I think in the security field it is a well-known fact that its not a good idea to let the web server vendor (e.g. Apache) and the version be visible to the outside as this can be used to launch targeted attacks against a specific server implementation.

I launched an Apache 2.4 Docker container to see whether that is still the case - and yes, it is.

I thought a bit about it. Wouldn't it be great to have a standard that web servers can implement against which defines a standard feature set that is versioned using semantic versioning?

This way, applications can still handle different server versions (which seems as the only reason why I would want to see the version from the outside) - but at least the vendor of the web server could be hidden. That would be at least one more hurdle an attacker has to deal with.

What do you think?

Comment: The standard feature set you are talking about is called HTTP(S)?

Comment: It's about as unsafe as it is safe to hide the server vendor/version. Hiding it is security through obscurity and provides only the shallowest of safety against the most ignorant attackers.

Comment: But seeing your proposed "standard header" will "tell" an attacker you're using at least version _x.yy_ of Apache, or at least version _a.bb_ of Nginx (the hypothetical versions where each adopted the use of standard headers). As answers here, and to a similar question about versions of an API note, _not_ showing a version is only a minor hindrance to an attacker, but can a pain-in-the-proverbial to someone supporting a system.

Comment: The main reason to hide the server version these days is so the PCI scan passes.

Comment: @Gloweye of course, I know that it wouldn't be an effective countermeasure if applied as the only one. But security is always about making it as hard for the attacker so that he gives up at some point because the hack value isn't worth the time he spends

Comment: _"I think in the security field it is a well-known fact that its not a good idea to let the web server vendor and the version be visible to the outside ..."_ - I don't think there's any real consensus on that.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yes, in theory by advertising vendor and version in the banner makes an attacker's job easier, but like only a little bit.

Even if you don't advertise it, it can be figured out from the behaviour of the app. Take for example, the network scanning tool nmap:

> Nmap provides a number of features for probing computer networks, including host discovery and service and operating system detection. These features are extensible by scripts that provide more advanced service detection, vulnerability detection, and other features.

Source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nmap)

> After TCP and/or UDP ports are discovered using one of the other scan methods, version detection interrogates those ports to determine more about what is actually running. The nmap-service-probes database contains probes for querying various services and match expressions to recognize and parse responses.

Source: [nmap documentation](https://nmap.org/book/man-version-detection.html).

Basically, nmap will start by trying to decide if it's apache / nginx / IIS, etc, which it will do by sending a specific packet to which it knows that the different web servers will respond differently. Then, once it knows that it's apache, it will send packets that target behaviours that have changed between one version and another, possibly because of a bug fix or because of a new feature.

As noted by @paj28 in comments, nmap is quite good at detecting the vendor, but hit-and-miss with version, when nmap displays detailed version info, that's probably because there was a banner. Of course, if you're trying to hack in, why bother trying to figure out version at all; once you know it's apache, why not just run all the apache exploit scripts from metasploit at it and see if any of them stick?

So yes, in theory it's possible to write a specification for "Here's how all web servers MUST behave", but that means that you're not allowing web servers to ever innovate, or fix bugs.  Moreover, web servers will want to differentiate themselves with features that other servers don't have.

As pointed out by @TripeHound, version banners can be considered a win for security as they allow sysadmins to easily inventory their systems and keep them up to date.

---

**TL;DR:** Banner or not, you can figure out what web server and OS you're talking to.

---

## Nmap Example

Since this post got popular, I'll add and some examples:

Apache httpd puts version info right in an HTTP header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 14:26:10 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
```

and unsurprisingly, nmap picks this up:

```
 ~ nmap 192.168.56.107 -p 80 -A --version-all

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-10-17 07:58 EDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.56.107
Host is up (0.0020s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
80/tcp open  http    Apache httpd 2.4.6 ((CentOS))
| http-methods:
|_  Potentially risky methods: TRACE
|_http-server-header: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
|_http-title: Apache HTTP Server Test Page powered by CentOS

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 14.23 seconds
```

If we try something a bit trickier, Apache Tomcat does not give an obvious banner:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: W/"1896-1527518937672"
Last-Modified: Mon, 28 May 2018 14:48:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1896
Date: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 14:35:05 GMT
Connection: close

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Apache Tomcat</title>
</head>
...
```

we see that nmap gets the vendor right, but does not have a guess at the version:

```
~ nmap -A -p 8080 192.168.56.1

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-10-17 10:34 EDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.56.1
Host is up (0.0013s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE VERSION
8080/tcp open  http    Apache Tomcat
| http-methods:
|_  Potentially risky methods: PUT DELETE
|_http-open-proxy: Proxy might be redirecting requests
|_http-title: Apache Tomcat

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 21.71 seconds
```

Comment: The banner can also be configured to lie, while fingerprinting based on behavior is a bit harder to mislead... I'd expect junior pen testers and script kiddies to be the only people who actually care about the banner.

Comment: While nmap can determine the type of server quite reliably, the determining the version is very hit and miss

Comment: I get that you might be able to work it out indirectly but how reliably?  One of my reoccurring annoyances is that vulnerability scanners keep 'finding' vulnerable Wordpress plugins running on our servers that don't even use PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt @paj28. I've rolled in more info about the reliability of version detection.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I think the web servers out there could be providing unique features while still giving out as little information as possible. The could come in a very secure default configuration that only offers the standard set of features and additional features would have to be configured by the admin. As I also learned, the order of the header fields in the response can be used for fingerprinting (e.g. IIS and Apache order the fields differently as far as I remember). Obviously that is a point that could be easily fixed.

Comment: Even if not configured to lie, the banner doesn't tell you if exploits are possible. Compile time flags and patches could have been applied to a given Apache version such that vulnerabilities are introduced (a feature was backported) or versions that have vulns out of the box have a patch applied. On the other hand, it's useful for admins when various middle boxes are involved (proxies, caches, load balancers, firewalls). If each middle box overwrites the server head, it's more obvious if routing is correct.

Answer (score 28):

Attackers just do not care. When you have a popular website, you find bots probing for every (vulnerable) version of phpmyadmin on every conceivable path, even when your site does not use a database at all. In the same manner, they probably probe for security holes in every version of, e.g., apache. Lying on or omitting the `Server` header does not buy you much security here.

But when you're the admin, you can use the `Server` header to quickly identify, if the server is still unpatched, what may prevent you from forgetting that you did not update, yet.

Of course your concerns are valid, e.g., when somebody is gathering information and may manually sort out exploits, that would work when they knew the right version, but in most cases it is just security by obscurity. The important point is, that you should make sure to keep the software updated, so you do not need to care about an attacker knowing that you run the latest version.

Comment: "*when you're the admin, you can use the Server header to quickly identify, if the server is still unpatched*" An administrator can look at the installed version on the system. That is not a reason to expose it to the whole internet.

Comment: Your scenario is, that you're working on the system. But the admin may for example scan the network and see what versions are reported by the servers and only connect to servers, where the automatic updated seems to fail (or the software may be on hold for some reason). Its like blocking icmp echo packets. It may hide a bit of your infrastructure, but it makes debugging network issues much harder.

Comment: If I need to rely on external sources to see what is inside my network, I have bigger issues. And I also think [blocking icmp is detrimental to the Internet](http://shouldiblockicmp.com/).

Comment: It is a debugging tool. You're free to turn it off, but it is useful to have it in many cases, e.g. debugging problems, interpreting bug reports by users and many more. The question here was not about if you can update your webserver without needing a header that tells you its version, but about why webservers still send the header by default.

Comment: The latest version isn't always the most secure, though.  Sometimes it's necessary to go backwards to resolve vulnerabilities.

Comment: @JimmyJames That makes no sense. If a flaw is discovered, the next version fixes it. It is not always mentioned in changelogs, so you often can't rely on those to tell you when you really need to update. Purposefully running an old version is almost always worse. And when a flaw is discovered that *only* affects the latest version and was due to new code that was not in previous versions (this is exceptional), then a new version is released that fixes that code, and you don't have to revert, either. The latest version is generally the right choice for security.

Comment: @Luc Sometimes new releases introduce new flaws.  When those flaws are discovered, there's not always a new release ready to go.  I'm not sure what doesn't make sense about that.

Comment: @Luc It's kind of strange that you say this "makes no sense" and then qualify every following statement: "*almost* always worse", "latest version is *generally* the right choice".  If this makes 'no sense', why aren't you absolute in your assertions to the contrary?  Also, your claim that it's 'exceptional' for new vulnerabilities to be introduced by new code is pretty strong.  Care to back that up?  It's not my experience and it's not hard to find examples.

Comment: @JimmyJames What I think makes no sense is stating in the general case that an old version may be more secure. If confidentiality and integrity are the thing you're going for, then generally one should always install updates. The qualifications are because there exist exceptions. I don't know where your "experience" comes from, but as someone whose day job is security, I am reasonably confident that it is actually exceptional (not unheard of, but nowhere near being a majority) for an old version to be more secure than the updated one and would rather ask you to back that uncommon opinion up.

Comment: @Luc "What I think makes no sense is stating in the general case that an old  version may be more secure."  What do you think the word 'sometimes' means?

Comment: @Luc " I am reasonably confident that it is actually exceptional (not unheard of, but nowhere near being a majority) for an old version to be more secure than the updated one".  There's a huge difference between being exceptional (very rare) and being no where near a majority (more than 50%)  If I thought this was a serious debate, I might take the time to provide some examples.   As someone who's worked in development for decades, I can tell you for sure that often new code means new bugs.  The main variable that changes that is testing.

Answer (score 14):

Historically, many servers returned headers like this:

> Server: Apache/2.4.1 (Unix) mod_php/1.2 mod_ssl/0.9

This does give away a bit more information than you want, so most servers now default to headers like this:

> Server: Apache

In fact, most web servers make it difficult to turn off this header. The reason? Marketing. They want to appear in surveys of what the most common web servers are.

Regarding fingerprinting, a number of tools can quite reliably determine Apache vs NGINX vs IIS, etc. But fingerprinting the version of a server is much harder, open source tools do not do it well, and it is impossible with any granularity.

Comment: I only have experience administering Apache httpd and Apache Tomcat servers. Both of those are astoundingly simply to change/remove the `Server` response header. nginx seems to have a similarly easy option to do so. So I'm not sure that "most web servers make it difficult to turn off this header" is accurate at all. Maybe "Microsoft IIS doesn't allow you to turn it off easily" is more accurate.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz - how exactly did you turn it off for Apache?

Answer (score 5):

As said, it's not a security issue to leave it, and it's a useful information for some client programs. Take `curl` for instance: it uses the `Server` header value to check if HTTP pipelining can be enabled:

Taken from https://serverfault.com/a/596560/347610

> [curl shows this message when run in verbose mode `-v`]:
>
> `* Server Apache/... is not blacklisted`
>
> It is an internal message from curl.
>   Seems to be part of a curl feature related to pipelining.

See also https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2013/03/26/better-pipelining-in-libcurl-7-30-0/

> a server blacklist [note: "based off the Server header"] that allows the application to specify a list of servers for which HTTP pipelining should not be attempted – real world tests has proven that some servers are too broken to be allowed to play the game

Hence why it's still enabled by default, and is totally harmless (just keep your server up to date). It's somehow the server's version of `User-Agent` header.

Comment: I did not know this was actually used by any software, I really thought the `Server` header was sent on every response just to be informative for the one-in-a-billion http responses seen by human eyes (or for statistics counting). Thanks for mentioning there is a practical reason to include a server header in the response!

Comment: If you remove the `Server` response header, it won't be blacklisted from `curl`'s pipelining features...

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz No, but if your server's version is in curl's blacklist, removing the `Server` header will make curl use pipelining while this server version support it wrong. Maybe some other web client use the same kind of scheme without stating so (or aren't in verbose mode), hence why leaving the `Server` header is a good idea (see RFC 7231 too).

Answer (score 1):

Because hiding version information is a weak security measure and a form of *security through obscurity*. The amount of security it adds is debatable, given that a) attackers can still fingerprint and probably determine your server, version and mods within a narrow margin of error and b) attackers can simply throw their whole library of exploits at you anyway.

In most scenarios, all you do is add a bit of time and effort for the attacker. The only scenario where you actually win something is if an attacker prepares a large attack by scanning entire networks to focus his later attack only on servers found vulnerable (i.e. he wants to compromise as many sites as possible in as short a time as possible) **and** he doesn't use fingerprinting or it doesn't work reliably on your site.

That's why turning off version information **in production** is one of those low-hanging fruits we usually do or advise simply because it does little harm and might do a little good, so why not?

During development, not being able to check the version from outside can cause additional work (log in to system, check there with commandline tools), or may not even be possible because the devs can't directly access the server, so in development version numbers are usually not turned off.

Your docker image does not know if it will be used for production or development. That's why it keeps version numbers on - it would do more harm in one setting than it does good in the other.